# How to run a class which is converted from String?

Tags: java, string, class, junit4

I have stored some class names in a HashMap. When user provides the name, that particular class should run. How can I do this? Any help please.

I did like below, but i am getting class not found exception.

```
Map<String,String> ruleMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    ruleMap.put("1", "CalculatorTest");
    ruleMap.put("2", "AreaTest")
JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
```

and calling method is,

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : ruleMap.entrySet()) 

    {
        Class c = null;

        if(selection.equals(entry.getKey()))
        {
            try 
            {
                c = Class.forName(entry.getValue());
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            junit.run(c); 
            break;
        }
    }
```

When I am calling like below it is working fine.

```
junit.run(CalculatorTest.class);
```

Comment: Is there no package for the class?

Comment: If `junit.run(CalculatorTest.class);` is working, then your `junit.run(c);` with `c` being the result of `Class.forName` should work too. Provided, of course, the class has no package as Roger points out. `Class.forName` has no knowledge of any `import` statements that may exist in the calling code (of course).

Comment: Side comment: you can replace the loop + if by `String value = ruleMap.get(selection); if(value != null) { c = Class.forName(value); }`

Comment: Yes. I have imported the package too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Peter Rader and Peter Lawrey commented Class.forName() will take full name of the class.
In my case my code should be,

```
ruleMap.put("1", "package.CalculatorTest");
```

Thanks to both Peter`s.. :)

Comment: Guess the name Peter is a category.

Answer (score 0):

Use full-qualified-classnames instead of simple classnames!

Try to use:

```
ruleMap.put("1", CalculatorTest.class.getName());
ruleMap.put("2", AreaTest.class.getName());
```

Regards

Comment: I guess "Class.forName" was ment to be named as "Class.forFullQualifiedNameWithPackageAndSoOn".

Comment: The Map's type parameter is String, Stirng. This code is just for testing purpose. Actual thing is I get class name from database.

Comment: If you can do that, you don't need Class.forName as you have the actual class i.e. just use `CalculatorTest.class`

Comment: @Samurai Your class name need to include the package name. You might assume your classes are in one package, you it needs to be determined in some manner.

Comment: Wowwwww.. Great Peter Rader.. I totally forget that.. Now its working fine.. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

junit.run(CalculatorTest.class);    means junit.run(Package.CalculatorTest );

So junit.run(c) does not work .

for example ,

package cocat.test.kmt;

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    String test =String.valueOf(Class.forName("cocat.test.kmt.Concat"));
  System.out.println(test);
}
```

when run this code the below result is show,

class cocat.test.kmt.Concat